# SwiftUI: Why does @State persist in subviews?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This seems like a simple question but I am struggling to find any resources about it online.

As an example, I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var parentText: String
    @State var childText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Parent Text", text: $parentText)
            TextField("Child Text", text: $childText)
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var parentText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(parentText)
            ChildView(parentText: $parentText)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ParentView()
}
```

To test, I ran this code and set child text to "C" and then the parent text to "P". This works fine and results in a view with P and C in the form. What I am wondering is why the child text is not set to the empty string once I update the parent text to "P".

My understanding of @State is that when parentText changes, the ParentView body will reload, which means it will reinitialize ChildView(), and I would expect childText to also be reinitialized to the empty string. Obviously, this is not the case.

Why does this happen? Is this just an optimization by Swift that I cannot generally rely on, or is this behavior predictable? If it is predictable, under what conditions will the child views State variables maintain their values?

Comment: State is a source of truth, Binding is a two way connection. While the body may be reloaded the value is coming from the parent, the child doesn’t have a value of its own. The Child’s State actually determines the identity of the ChildView so unless it decides to reload the value won’t reset. You can force in many ways but it isn’t ideal.

Comment: Really good question by the way! Everyone should learn this instead of avoiding it and instead trying to put state into their own custom view model classes which will eventually totally fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a language level, the `@State` property wrapper is translated to something like this (for `childText`):

```
private var _childText: State<String> = State(wrappedValue: "")

var childText: String {
    get { _childText.wrappedValue }
    nonmutating set { _childText.wrappedValue = newValue }
}

var $childText: String {
    get { _childText.projectedValue }
}
```

The only stored property here is `_childText`, so whenever `ChildView.init` is called, the initialiser call `State(wrappedValue: "")` gets run.

As Cheolhyun's answer says, each `@State` has its own persistent storage somewhere in memory. When `State(wrappedValue: "")` gets run for the first time, this persistent storage is allocated and initialised to have an initial value of `""`, and `_childText.wrappedValue` and `.projectedValue` both refer to that storage location.

As you said, when `parentText` updates, `ParentView.body` is evaluated, and hence `ChildView.init` and `State(wrappedValue: "")` gets run again. This time, however, `State(wrappedValue: "")` doesn't allocate a new storage. SwiftUI finds that the `ChildView` hasn't changed its *identity*, so it reuses the same storage. It initialises `_childText` in such a way that `_childText.wrappedValue` and `.projectedValue` both refer to that old storage location.

Note that "*identity*" mentioned above is a very important concept in SwiftUI. The WWDC video ["Demystifying SwiftUI"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) explains what *identity* is in detail.

As a simple example, we can set `ChildView`'s identity using the `id` modifier. Let's make it so that its identity is `parentText`, so that every time `parentText` changes, `ChildView` changes its identity.

```
ChildView(parentText: $parentText).id(parentText)
```

Now, when you change `parentText`, you can see that the child text text field resets to an empty string. The two text fields also loses focus, because they are now two completely different text fields from before, and that's because the `ChildView` now is a completely different `ChildView` from before, and that's because `ChildView`'s identity changed.

Comment: I think you should remove the property wrapper info and focus on identity, perhaps show a path of identities to explain it

Comment: @malhal I think the lowering of the property wrapper is very important. It shows that when `ChildView.init` is called, there is more going on than just "initialise `childText` to `""`". It is to show that the "magic"  is in `State.init`.

Comment: @malhal Also, I think the other answer already explains this pretty well on a high level of abstraction, so I decided to explain this with more focus on the language-level constructs.

Comment: You're right, I added an answer expanding on what the $ syntax means and why it doesnt make a dependency on body

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the following two articles helpful.

- https://doordash.engineering/2022/05/31/how-the-swiftui-view-lifecycle-and-identity-work/

> `@State`
>
> *State* is a source of truth for the view and it’s used when the scope of changes is limited to the view only. **By wrapping value types as transient** [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) properties, **the framework allocates a persistent storage for this value type** and makes it a dependency, so changes to the state will automatically be reflected in the view.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

> **SwiftUI manages the property’s storage.** When the value changes, SwiftUI updates **the parts of** the view hierarchy that depend on the value.

To summarize, `@State` is managed by the SwiftUI framework in a **special repository.**
Therefore, the behavior your code shows is quite predictable.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have good info but I thought I'd add some more:

View structs have an "identity" its like their path in the View hierarchy. State is persisted at that path no matter how many times the View struct at that path is re-init.

Also, the `$parentText` syntax is sugar for `Binding(get: { parentText } }, set: { parentText = $0 })` so as you can see it doesn't read the var until the `get` closure is called, this means there is no dependency of `body` on the value of `parentText`. So if no call to `self.parentText` exists, then `body` won't even be called when `parentText` is set by an action or a child `View`. `body` is only called when a state is set if it was previously read. A lot of people get tripped up on this.

So a lot of magic goes on in the `View` struct, persistent values based on path in the hierarchy and dependency tracking for efficient calls to `body`. It goes even further with `EqualityView` which is how you decide if `body` should be called based on values the struct was init with rather than using the default comparison!